# Decimals in Jtable not displaying correctly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, decimal

Good evening,

I've got a JTable with data from a SQL table. I have a column in the SQL table with decimal values (for example, 44.44) but in the JTable it shows as 44.00. So somehow the JTable (or the input field) is rounding off the value to the nearest whole number (which is what i do not want).

I tried using Table Renderer, but it's not giving me the desired results (or i'm overlooking something)

Code for the table renderer:

```
static class DecimalFormatRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
      private static final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#,###.00" );

      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
         JTable pickTable, Object value, boolean isSelected,
         boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {


         Number number = (Number) value;
         value = formatter.format((Number)value);


         return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            pickTable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column );
      }
   }
```

this code loads the date from the SQL Table into the JTable:

```
private void LoadPickTable() {
        ArrayList<Pick> pick = ListPick(pickFilterTxt1.getText());
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID", "ARTIKELCODE", "LOCATIE", "OMSCHRIJVING", "EENHEID", "CODE","HAL","AANTAL","INITIAAL"});
        Object[] rij = new Object[9];
        pickTable.setFont(new Font("Barlow", Font.PLAIN, 22));


        for (int i = 0; i < pick.size(); i++) {
            rij[0] = pick.get(i).getId();
            rij[1] = pick.get(i).getArtiekelcode();
            rij[2] = pick.get(i).getLocatie();
            rij[3] = pick.get(i).getOmschrijving();
            rij[4] = pick.get(i).getEenheid();
            rij[5] = pick.get(i).getCode();
            rij[6] = pick.get(i).getHal();
            rij[7] = pick.get(i).getAantal();
            rij[8] = pick.get(i).getInitiaal();
            model.addRow(rij);
        }

        pickTable.setModel(model);
        pickTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(new DecimalFormatRenderer());

    }
```

The Input field i'm using to test is a JComboBox (pickAantalCombo), the code:

```
private void ModifyPick() {

        int row = pickTable.getSelectedRow();
        String cell = pickTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
        String sql = "UPDATE PICKLOCATIES SET artikelcode=?,locatie=?,omschrijving=?, eenheid=?, hal=?, aantal=?, initiaal=? WHERE ID=" + cell;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            String code = (String) pickArticleCombo.getSelectedItem();
            pst.setString(1, code);
            String loc = (String) pickLocationCombo.getSelectedItem();
            String hal = (String) halCombo.getSelectedItem();
            String decimal = (String) pickAantalCombo.getSelectedItem();


            pst.setString(1, code);
            pst.setString(2, loc);
            pst.setString(3, pickDescriptionTxt.getText());
            pst.setString(4, eenheidTxt.getText());
            pst.setString(5, hal);
            pst.setString(6,decimal);
            pst.setString(7, pickInitiaalTxt.getText());

            pst.executeUpdate();
            LoadPickTable();
            ClearPickFields();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Artikel Aangepast!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Screenshot of the JTable:

[JTable Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5OZF.png)

Screenshot of the SQL Table:

[SQL Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjN9Z.png)

The input value in the input field is, of course, 44.44.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the return type of the `getAantal()` method in class `Pick`?

Comment: It appears in your `DecimalFormatRenderer` class you are converting the value to a number `Number number = (Number) value;` that alone will remove the decimal from your value leaving the variable number to 44, and when when you apply your formatter, you get the 44.00

Comment: @Cujoey Casting does not change the object.  If it was a Double, Float, or BigDecimal before, casting will not change that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an other error: ever table now needs its own row object, otherwise you are overwriting every row's fields with the last rows' fields.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pick.size(); i++) {
    Object[] rij = new Object[9];
```

You should ensure, that the read Number is not integral.

```
rij[7] = (BigDecimal) pick.get(i).getAantal();
```

I suspect `getAantal` to deliver an int.

At the moment the table fields seem to always be string:

```
        pst.setBigDecimal(6, new BigDecimal(decimal));
```

Then there is still the problem of decimal point versus comma, but I leave it at this.

Try debugging.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback, I'll have a look